# firefox addon using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, firefox-addon

html file:

```
<html ng-app="IDAddon" ng-csp>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/angular-csp.css">
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="somepopup">
        Delayed Message: {{textmessage}}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js script:

```
function MainController($scope, suggestionService) {
   $scope.getMessage = function() {
      window.addEventListener("message", function (){
         $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.textmessage = 'Fetched after 3 seconds';
         });
      } , false);
   }

$scope.getMessage();
}

var IDmodule = angular.module('IDAddon', []).controller('MainCtrl', MainController)
```

I can confirm that the "message" event is received and the event handler function is called, but the page never gets updated with the message.
Am I missing anything here?

Comment: angular can be used but it has to be from .xhtml pages or from the page loaded in the contentFrame. can you upload your full addon code to github and link it here ill take a look i have some experience with angular

Comment: If you still need help with this be sure to include @Noitidart in your comment/reply so it gets my attenion and i see your reply.